# Strange behavior using live event on IE10 with jQuery

Tags: events, jquery, live

I have the following code:

```
$('input.test2').live('keyup', function (e) {
});

$('input.test1').live('change', function (e) {
});
```

test1 and test2 are classes of the same input element.. but only the test1 is triggered.

Can somebody explain to me why this is happening? (It only happens on IE10).
I tried to return false or e.stopPropagation() but nothing changed.

Comment: but what is happening ?

Comment: "Can anyone explain to me why this is happening" .. why what is happening?

Comment: why the second one isn't triggered...  if i change the 'change' to 'click' it works fine :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using "on" instead of "live"

```
$('input.test1').on('change', function (e) {
});

$('input.test2').on('keyup', function (e) {
});
```

As per the jQuery docs:
http://api.jquery.com/live/

"As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to attach event handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use .delegate() in preference to .live()."

Comment: The syntax for `on` is completely different from the syntax for `live`, so you can't just replace the method name. You have replaced the delegates with regular bindings, so if the elements doesn't exist at the time that they are bound, the events will never be handled.